# Qt - How do I use the same Image in two different buttons?

Tags: c++, qt

Okay so I have a problem in Qt, I have an image that I loaded with QImage that I need to work with in the rest of my application. I load up an image by using a PushButton, which then displays the image using QPixmap.

I had to use dynamic memory allocation so the image displayed won't auto-delete after the event finished. But now the problem comes in when I need the image loaded in the first Button, in other ones to work with them. So I'm guessing I need to declare these global right? How will I do it here in Qt? And do I just delete my widgets when the form closes by using *delete()*?

Here is a block of my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
/*Open the image using a File Dialog so the user selects his own image.
  Note: Image is best to be kept at 150x150, therefore image
  will be scaled down to the aforementioned ratio.*/

QString imageFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open Image","C:/","Formats (*.bmp *.png)");

if (!imageFile.isEmpty())
{
    // Test the image, if it isn't empty, image will be the loaded image from dialog.
    QImage image(imageFile);

    if(image.isNull())
    {
        // Error displaying image -> display message dialog box.
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error", "There was a problem displaying your image, make sure that is one of the supported formats.", "OK");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Image Load", "Your image was successfully opened.","OK");
        return;
    }
}

QImage *imageOriginal = new QImage(150,150, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
imageOriginal->load(imageFile);

QLabel *labelOriginal = new QLabel(this);
labelOriginal->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*imageOriginal));
labelOriginal->setGeometry(ui->title1->x(), ui->title1->y()+30, 150, 150);
labelOriginal->show();
labelOriginal->deleteLater();
}
```

Everything is working fine so far, I just need to get a way to use them in the other events too. I need to process the image by changing it's color values, etc. and showing all the different changes next to the original.

Comment: Are you familiar with the resource system? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: I'll definitely check that out, thanks DaveyLaser!